# Apollo writeFragment not updating data

Tags: caching, graphql, react-apollo

In react-apollo 2.0.1 I have a graphql type that looks like this:

```
type PagedThing {
  data: [Thing]
  total: Int
}
```

When doing the following writeFragment

```
  client.writeFragment({
    id,
    fragment: gql`
      fragment my_thing on Thing {
        status
      }
    `,
    data: {
      status
    }
  })
```

The cache is not update and the new data is not shown on the UI. Is there something else that need to be done?

PS: To be safe I used [fragment matching](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/master/docs/source/recipes/fragment-matching.md)

Edit 1:

I receive an error of:

> Cannot match fragment because __typename property is missing: {"status":"online"}

So I changed the code to:

```
client.writeFragment({
    id,
    fragment: gql`
      fragment my_thing on Thing {
        status
      }
    `,
    data: {
      __typename: 'Thing',
      status
    }
  })
```

And no error is thrown but the updated still do not happen

Comment: Closed page. Immediately, in a rush, reoponed to make sure I upvoted both question and answer. Whew.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Turns out I needed to not only add the __typename as the ID needed to be the one resolved by default (Explained [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/#writequery-and-writefragment))

So I needed to do the following in order to make it work:

```
client.writeFragment({
  id: `Thing:${id}`,
  fragment: gql`
    fragment my_thing on Thing {
      status
    }
  `,
  data: {
    __typename: 'Thing',
    status
  }
})
```

Comment: Prefixing the `id` with the typename was the key, thank you!

Comment: You should probably use:
`id: defaultDataIdFromObject({ id: parentId, __typename: parentType })...`

Imported from : `import { defaultDataIdFromObject } from "apollo-cache-inmemory";`


just if you want to override defaultDataIdFromObject in your apollo client setup in the future

Comment: The documentation around this method leaves a lot to be desired, it has to be said.

Comment: The link is dead for me. What was the explanation?

Comment: Updated the link with some equivalent. The cause is the ID not matching the default resolved id with __typename, although on the example it only adds the __typename on writeQuery at the time of the answer it was needed to add it on writeFragment as well.Not sure if no __typename works on writeFragment right now

Comment: What if it is list that I'm updating. I know we need to read the fragment first add the new item to the list and write the fragment. In my case reading the fragment is working but its unable to update the newly added item to the cache. Any inputs?

Answer (score 1):

it appears that the framework has been extended to provide a method called 'identify' to avoid this problem (in case they change implementation later)

```
cache.modify({
  id: cache.identify(myPost),
             ^
  fields(fieldValue, details) {
    return details.INVALIDATE;
  },
});
```

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/#example-invalidating-fields-within-a-cached-object